# Working with content acquired via jquery load?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've managed to use jQuery `.load()` to get the contents of a table from another web page and insert it into the current page, which works fine. However, if I run scripts after which use the newly-loaded data, they return as undefined.

index.htm

```
<table>
    <tr id="newTr"></tr>
</table>
<span id="newSpan"></span>
<script>
    $('#newTr').load('page2.htm #oldTr');
    var newData = document.getElementById("newTr").getElementsByTagName("td");
    document.getElementById("newSpan").innerHTML = newData[0].innerHTML;
</script>
```

page2.htm

```
<table>
    <tr id="oldTr">
        <td>content I want in newSpan</td>
        <td>more content</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

For the last line of the `script`, I get a TypeError saying that `newData[0]` is undefined. But if I copy and paste the same line into the browser console, it executes correctly and the `td` content is copied to the `span`. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: That the content is undefined? Can you please post the specific error that you are getting?

Comment: jQuery's `load()` function is asynchronous, meaning it will send that request to get the information, and will proceed with the rest of the code. The next line then runs immediately, before the content is loaded. You can use another parameter in your `load()` to declare a callback function (i.e. complete) that runs the next line. That way, it will wait until the content is loaded to run the rest of the applicable code.

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/load/  The last argument you can give to load is a success method, that will execute after the load has inserted the content from the ajax request onto the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try putting the code that works with the loaded content inside the complete callback function:

```
$('#newTr').load('page2.htm #oldTr', function() {
  var newData = document.getElementById("newTr").getElementsByTagName("td");
  document.getElementById("newSpan").innerHTML = newData[0].innerHTML;
});
```

Or, since you're already using jQuery:

```
$('#newTr').load('page2.htm #oldTr', function() {
  $('#newSpan').html($('#newTr').find('td').html());
});
```